# Firebase Change Permissions Public Access SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, image, swiftui, storage

I am using Firebase for Auth and image storage--images that are publically available thoughout my app, like profile pictures. How do I set up the permissions appropriately so that any user (or even non-authenticated entities) can read these public images?

My security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your Firebase rules won't be affected at all by what UI framework you use -- the SwiftUI part isn't going to be relevant here. Can you edit the question with your current Firebase Storage rules (with anything sensitive removed)?

Comment: updated post. These rules don't look sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you say that you want non-authenticated entities to see the images, but your rules are set up to *only* allow authenticated entities to see them. You can change your rules to:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read; 
            allow write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew my rules weren't set up right but wasn't sure how to change.